# Haskell IO with Websockets

Tags: haskell, io, websocket

Using the [`websockets`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets) library in the following way

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Network.Socket hiding (recv)
import Network.WebSockets
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Debug.Trace
import Control.Applicative

fetch :: IO B.ByteString
fetch = do
  B.putStrLn "connected"
  [v4] <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "127.0.0.1") (Just "3000")
  c <- socket (addrFamily  v4) Stream 0x6
  c `connect` (addrAddress v4)
  recv c 512000

proxy :: TextProtocol p => WebSockets p ()
proxy = sendTextData . unsafePerformIO $! fetch

app :: Request -> WebSockets Hybi00 ()
app r = acceptRequest r >> r `traceShow` proxy

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $! runServer "0.0.0.0" 4000 app
```

causes `fetch` to occur only once and all websocket clients receive the same not fresh data.

- How can I do arbitrary IO with `websockets`?
- How can I get the above example to work with fresh `fetch`es?

I would love to hear any suggestions or complete solutions. A way of doing it without touching `iteratee` would be exceptionally appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, the reason it only occurs once is because you use `unsafePerformIO` (shame on you! :) ).  GHC assumes that multiple calls to a pure function can be combined into a single cached call to that function.  This is one of many reasons why it's almost always a bad idea to use `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebSockets` monad is an instance of the [MonadIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t%3aMonadIO) typeclass, so you can do arbitrary IO-operations with the `liftIO` function.

In this case I'm guessing you want to do

```
proxy = liftIO fetch >>= sendTextData
```

You also need to add the import

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
```